# Can a C# object be 'null' but still have properties?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object for which I can print its properties (like 'name', 'id',...) in a debug console.
On the very next line, I print the object itself, and there I get 'null'. Kind of like this:

```
Debug.Log($"Item name is {item.name}");
Debug.Log($"Item is {item}");
if (item == null)
{
    Debug.Log("Yes, item is null!");
}
```

So the first line will print a correct name, the second prints 'null'. The third line prints "Yes, item is null!".

How is that possible?
(I don't know if this is relevant, but this happens in a code for Unity.)

Thank you,
Arnaud.

Answer (score 5):

That's because UnityEngine.Object overload `==`, `!=` and `bool` operators.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_eq.html

A Unity object will equal to null after it is destroyed, but you can still access part of its properties.

You can use the following condition to check whether a Unity object is completely null or not.

```
(object)item == null
```

Comment: Hello, I found out that this 'item' object was an instance of a class that was inheriting from Monobehaviour, which was actually not required (because that object is just holding some properties). By removing that class' inheritance from Monobehaviour, it now works. I guess when you instantiate an object inheriting from Monobehaviour, it doesn't behave as I was expecting..? So, somehow the 'Object' was not instantiated, but the properties of item were still passed? Anyways, it seems related to what you say about that operators overload by Object,indeed.I'm just not sure to fully understand :D

Comment: This 'item' object has been instatiated but somehow it was marked as destroyed (or missing) by Unity. So it's actually a valid object in C#, but the overloaded operator will just tell you it's equal to null.